# Facing with global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have faced the variable problem in JavaScript. I declared `var checkable = [];` to be global.`checkable` will be contained the elements after this function `function success(position)`. At the last line, I called `document.write(checkable[0]);` to be printed in HTML, but it turned out that `checkable` is undefined. I don't understand why this variable has no any elements even if I did `checkable.push(checkpoint[i]);`. Please, help me to figure it out.

```js
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("test_radar");
var checkpoint = ["ICT","OP","SH","EG","Library"];
var latitude = [13.794411,13.794391,13.792634,13.795725,13.794443];
var longitude = [100.324581,100.325594,100.324870,100.325874,100.324168];
var checkable = [];
var myla;
var mylo;

function success(position) {

 myla = position.coords.latitude+0;
 mylo = position.coords.longitude+0;


 var s = document.querySelector('#status');

 if (s.className == 'success') {   
  return;
 }

 s.innerHTML = " Found you!";
 s.className = 'success';

 var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
 mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
 mapcanvas.style.height = '0px';
 mapcanvas.style.width = '0px';

 document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myla, mylo);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 18,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng, 
  map: map, 
  title:"You are here! (at least within a "+position.coords.accuracy+" meter radius)"
 });

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
 var check = 0, ncheck = 0;
 var r = 0.0006;
 var search = 0.003;
 var i = 0;
 
 var near = [];

 x.innerHTML = "My Latitude: " + myla + "<br>My Longitude: \t" + mylo + "<br><br>Chackinable CheckPoint: ";
 for(i=0;i<latitude.length;i++) {
  if(latitude[i]<(myla+search) && (myla-search)<latitude[i] && 
     longitude[i]<(mylo+search) && (mylo-search)<longitude[i]){
   if(latitude[i]<(myla+r) && (myla-r)<latitude[i] && 
      longitude[i]<(mylo+r) && (mylo-r)<longitude[i]){
    checkable.push(checkpoint[i]);
    //x.innerHTML = "Hi";
    check++;
   }
   else{
    near.push(checkpoint[i]);
    //x.innerHTML = "Hi2";
    ncheck++;
   }

  }
 }
 
 
 
 if(check==0){
  x.innerHTML += "No CheckPoint avilable.<br>";
 }
 else {
  x.innerHTML += checkable + "<br>Near Checkpoint: ";
  
  if(ncheck==0){
   x.innerHTML += "No near CheckPoint avilable.<br>";
  }
  else {
   x.innerHTML += near + "<br>";
  }
 }

 var d = new Date();
 
 x.innerHTML += "<br>Date&Time of the lastest Scan: " + d.toLocaleDateString() + " | "  + d.toLocaleTimeString();
 setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
 
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}

function myTimer() {
 var d = new Date();
 document.getElementById("test_clock").innerHTML = "Time: " + d.toLocaleDateString() + " | " + d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

document.write(checkable[0]);

</script>
```

Comment: call function `success` in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Thats because `checkable[0]` is initialized inside `success()` and you have not yet called it.

Comment: because you did not call `success` function yet.

Comment: @AtikurRahman yes that is the case